# Searching for entry with id in comma separated list in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get entries from a mysql table, which contain a given id within a comma separated list. I want to use regular expressions and the LIKE selector.

My current approach looks like this

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE list LIKE '%,0,%';
```

with the problem being that this ignores the first and last element in a list like '0,1,2,3'.

I've tried using the | or operator to test for all possible cases.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE list LIKE '(%,0,%)|(^0,%)';
```

I've tried this with and without the ^ character and with and without the parenthesis, but in all cases this approach didn't even match the characters in the middle. In fact, the or operator doesn't seem to be working in even the simplest expressions like

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE list LIKE '%(1|2)%';
```

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate commas to the start and the end of the list:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE concat(',', list, ',') LIKE '%,0,%';
```

Answer (score 4):

You should fix your data model!  DO not store lists of things -- especially numbers -- in a string.  SQL has a great data model for storing lists:  it is called a **table**.

If you are stuck with someone else's really, really, really bad choice of dta model, you can work around in.  MySQL has a handy function, `find_in_set()`, that does what you want:

```
WHERE find_in_set('0', list) > 0
```

Comment: I know it's bad practice, but I'm working on a pretty simple project and I'm a bit overwhelmed by all of the different options and functions mysql has. I don't know how to link a table from a field in another table and I feel like this would just make everything more prone to errors and I'd eventually mess something up, especially when porting the project to a new system. I am not quite sure about find_in_set. Wouldn't that also find a 1 when only a 10 is in the list? Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Snooze . . . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set.